# How to Iterate Over json Object for Key Value in EJS Template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have json object like below and trying to renter it in select control for key value.

```
var FieldTypes = {
  Text: 1,
  TextArea: 2,
  CheckBox: 3,
  CheckboxMultiple: 4,
  Select: 5,
  Radio: 6,
  File: 7,
  Date: 8,
  Number: 9
};
```

Here is what i did but in this way i am only getting keys not values.

```
<select>
    <% Object.keys(fieldtypes).forEach(function(key) { %>
       <option value="<%= fieldtypes[key] %>">?</option>
    <% }); %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<%=` tag to also output keys into the template:

```
<select>
    <% Object.keys(fieldtypes).forEach(function(key) { %>
       <option value="<%= fieldtypes[key] %>"><%= key %></option>
    <% }); %>
</select>
```